# Get Focus back to child node in Tree Table

Tags: oracle-adf, treetable

I have a Tree-Table and whenever an action is performed on child node,the treetable is refreshed and the focus goes back to parent node. The problem is , if the parent node has many child nodes , one will have to scroll down to get to the child nodes and once the tree table is refreshed after any action performed , focus goes back to parent row. I need the focus to stay on the child node. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get focus on a specific component in the backingbean in any action listener, I guess you can use this to get focus on your child component as well.

```
    ExtendedRenderKitService service = Service.getRenderKitService(facesContext, ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
    String clientId = uIComponent.getClientId(facesContext);
    service.addScript(facesContext, "(AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent('"+clientId+"')).focus();");
```